# Is there some Android event for user freeing space in device?

Tags: android, file, events

I'd like to know if such an event exists in Android so when it happens I can make an Android receiver to fire a service that would help to refresh some data related to the free space available.

I'm not sure about how the deletion of files works in Android, maybe deleting some file doesn't really free space meaning that it just marks the space as that it can be used to put other files on it, if this were the case I'd like to know if reacting to such an event would be possible.

Per request [I'm giving all the events](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#inhmethods) (well in reality they are called Constants) that app in theory could react to, there doesn't seem to be one that could help me with this.

Comment: Have you tried searching for lists of all events, i.e. done some research first?

Comment: Yes, none of them looked like could help with this.

Comment: I suggest you demonstrate that by editing your question to include the link to the list of events.

Answer (score 0):

Android OS will delete cache files and free some memory on the device once it decides that it runs low on disk space. Ultimately, you never need to do this manually, and actually you can not do this since you don't have access to other files apart from your app files. Of course, you can delete any files created by your app (unless they were put inside the public directory).

Comment: I think he's asking how to hook into Android prompting the user to delete stuff, like mine just did in order to install the SO app.

Comment: From the question that's not so clear. If so, he'll need to create a BroadcastReceiver for this, yet I believe there is already one in Android OS